# disable php, but allow in subdirectory

Tags: apache-2.2, php, ubuntu-12.04

I want to disable php for all my user directories, which I implemented by adding `php_admin_value engine Off` to them:

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`:

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir "public_html"
    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        php_admin_value engine Off
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

But I want one user (myself) to be able to execute php, but only in one subdirectory. I tried to follow https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UserDirectoryPHP, which specified creating a new file with following lines (I don't think it matters if it's separated to `conf.d` but it's cleaner imo so I complied):

`/etc/apache2/d.conf/php-in-homedirs.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        <Directory /home/gunther/public_html/php>
            php_admin_value engine on
        </Directory>
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

These instructions *are* added to the apache config, as I can see in the server-info:

```
Module Name: mod_php5.c
Content handlers: yes
...
Current Configuration:

<VirtualHost *:80>
  11:   <Directory /home/*/public_html>
  12:     php_admin_value engine Off
    :   </Directory>
    : </VirtualHost>
In file: /etc/apache2/conf.d/php-in-homedirs.conf
   2: <Directory /home/gunther/public_html/php/*>
   3:   php_admin_value engine On
    : </Directory>
```

But it just ain't working, it downloads the php file. If I remove the `php_admin_value engine off` from the `default` vhost, php works, but then it works for all users in all directories. I just want it working for that one subdirectory.

Comment: have you tried to copy-paste the content of php-in-homedirs.conf in the default file *before* the /home/*/public_html section ? ( and remove the php-in-homedirs.conf ) ?

Comment: I tried by switching the position of `Includes sites-enabled` and `Include conf.d` in `apache2.conf`, didn't work. Just tried what you suggested, although that would change not much imo -> no results either :/

Comment: Is it normal that your home directory is referenced as /media/data/gunther instead of /home/gunther ? Reading again your conf I do not see how the engine Off  on /home/*/public_html would affect the /media/data/gunther/public_html ??

Comment: oops, that's supposed to be `/home/gunther/public_html/php` I copied the wrong things

Comment: Did you try / is it possible to set the variable to Off at the virtual host level, and setting it "On" only in <Directory /home/gunther/public_html/php/> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand it, it's a combination of how to use `php_admin_value engine` and precedence of apache configuration files.

If I put the dis/enable next to eachother *and* use `engine 1` instead of `engine on`, it works, all other combinations do *not* work. If anybody has an explanation, please tell!

I ended up putting the php enable/disable of userdirs in the `php5.conf` file:

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        php_admin_value engine Off
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/gunther/public_html/php>
        php_admin_value engine 1
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

which by default gets loaded before `sites-enabled` and `conf.d`.

Answer (score 1):

The order of precedence that Apache uses to merge directives in different sections is described [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html#mergin).  It can be hard to get right, and this seems to be a case where the precedence is unclear and not what you want or expect.

In a case like that you can force the precedence you want by changing your `<Directory>` section to one with higher precedence, for example:

```
<DirectoryMatch ^/home/gunther/public_html/php/> ... </DirectoryMatch>
```

or

```
<Location /~gunther/php> ... </Location>
```

Comment: Using Location for this is very likely to be a bad idea. You want to disable /enable php for directories/files, not for urls.

Comment: tried all of those, but neither is working. If I reverse the enable/disable, ie turn the php engine on in `public_html` and off in `public_html/php`, this does work. Is it possible that you can only override `engine on` and not `engine off`?