# Disable PHP in subdirectory, but allow in parent directory

Tags: apache-2.2, php, ubuntu-12.04

I'm using multiple virtual hosts on Ubuntu and want to disable PHP in a sub-directory from within httpd.conf (not from .htaccess)

Here is the virtual host's configurations

```
<VirtualHost subdomain.website.com>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/subdomain
    ServerName subdomain.website.com

    <Directory /var/www/html/subdomain>
        allow from all
        Options None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/subdomain/nophp>
        php_flag engine off
        AddType text/plain php

        Options All Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

but, it ignores the second block of `<Directory ...>`

Actually its a reverse question of [disable php, but allow in subdirectory](https://serverfault.com/questions/577649/disable-php-but-allow-in-subdirectory)

Comment: Have you tried using `<Location>` directives instead?

Comment: This question has been already answered:

[Apache: Disable php in a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776350/apache-disable-php-in-a-directory)

[Disable PHP in directory (including all sub-directories) with .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271899/disable-php-in-directory-including-all-sub-directories-with-htaccess)

Comment: @GregL Yes, I tried with `<Location>` too but no success.

Comment: @Panagiotis I'm sorry, if you read the question, I want it without using `.htaccess`. Actually, `nophp` directory is fully writeable. User can upload/overwrite any file there - including `.htaccess`.